# Solid settling to the top of solution when centrifuged

Tags: density, centrifugal-force

I have a mixture of dense particles (about 4x that of water) and not-so-dense particles (maybe the same density of water or slightly less or more dense). When I centrifuge a tube filled with a solution of these particles in water, the tube is on an angle and I find that the denser particles settle to the outer wall of the tube. But the less dense particles also settle - they settle on the inner wall of the tube and form a thick layer.

I am not sure why this happens. I would assume that rather than rise to the top, the particles would remain suspended in the solution as the centrifugal force is not strong enough to allow them to settle. However, there still appears to be particles in the liquid afterwards. If interested, I use 7000 rpm for 30 minutes.

Comment: Sounds kinda like thick blood...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your description ("the tube is on an angle") correctly, then the "outer" wall of the tube is where the centrifugal force is pointing - and the "inner" wall is the opposite side.

When the tube is spinning, there will be an apparent radial force on all the particles - the lighter particles will experience a "buoyancy" towards the inner wall, and the heavier particles a "gravity" towards the outer wall.

Once they get there, they may not want to slide since to do so, they would have to displace other particles that are already there - or perhaps the friction with the wall is such that they don't want to move. Without a diagram / photo, it's hard to tell you exactly what is going on.